# Counting data points, grouped by country, occupation, and age, for charting

Tags: javascript, performance, array, json

I would like to chart my data. However, the data I get from server needs to be
completely transformed, and I would like to transform it as quick as possible. I believed reduce would be the best way to go about this in linear time. However, I am not sure if I am fully exploiting it.

- The data from server needs to be reorganized into three categories: **country**, **occupation**, and **age**
- When I encounter a country, occupation, or age, I need to group them under their appropriate category and increment their count.

In my code, I am using reduce to loop over the items once. I am hashing to find duplicates. I am <s>using *some*</s> also hashing to locate the category titles in the nested arrays in order to increment the count.

This is the original data:

```
var object = {
  dataset: [
    {
      name: "Sarah",
      age: "23",
      gender: "female",
      country: "australia",
      occupation: "student"
    },
    {
      name: "Randy",
      age: "19",
      gender: "male",
      country: "america",
      occupation: "student"
    },
    {
      name: "Roger",
      age: "32",
      gender: "male",
      country: "germany",
      occupation: "software professional"
    },
    {
      name: "Maverick",
      age: "10",
      gender: "male",
      country: "america",
      occupation: "student"
    },
    {
      name: "Riya",
      age: "25",
      gender: "female",
      country: "australia",
      occupation: "software professional"
    },
    {
      name: "Glade",
      age: "30",
      gender: "female",
      country: "India",
      occupation: "teacher"
    }
  ]
};
```

This is the desired transformation:

```
[
  {
    "name": "country",
    "dataset": [
      {
        "value": "australia",
        "count": 2,
        "color": "#878BB6"
      },
      {
        "value": "america",
        "count": 2,
        "color": "#878BB6"
      },
      {
        "value": "germany",
        "count": 1,
        "color": "#878BB6"
      },
      {
        "value": "India",
        "count": 1,
        "color": "#878BB6"
      }
    ]
  }
] [
  {
    "name": "occupation",
    "dataset": [
      {
        "value": "student",
        "count": 3,
        "color": "#878BB6"
      },
      {
        "value": "software professional",
        "count": 2,
        "color": "#878BB6"
      },
      {
        "value": "teacher",
        "count": 1,
        "color": "#878BB6"
      }
    ]
  }
] [
  {
    "name": "age",
    "dataset": [
      {
        "value": "23",
        "count": 1,
        "color": "#878BB6"
      },
      {
        "value": "19",
        "count": 1,
        "color": "#878BB6"
      },
      {
        "value": "32",
        "count": 1,
        "color": "#878BB6"
      },
      {
        "value": "10",
        "count": 1,
        "color": "#878BB6"
      },
      {
        "value": "25",
        "count": 1,
        "color": "#878BB6"
      },
      {
        "value": "30",
        "count": 1,
        "color": "#878BB6"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is my working code:

```js
const object = {
  dataset: [{
      name: "Sarah",
      age: "23",
      gender: "female",
      country: "australia",
      occupation: "student"
    },
    {
      name: "Randy",
      age: "19",
      gender: "male",
      country: "america",
      occupation: "student"
    },
    {
      name: "Roger",
      age: "32",
      gender: "male",
      country: "germany",
      occupation: "software professional"
    },
    {
      name: "Maverick",
      age: "10",
      gender: "male",
      country: "america",
      occupation: "student"
    },
    {
      name: "Riya",
      age: "25",
      gender: "female",
      country: "australia",
      occupation: "software professional"
    },
    {
      name: "Glade",
      age: "30",
      gender: "female",
      country: "India",
      occupation: "teacher"
    }
  ]
};




var mapping = Object.values(object.dataset).reduce(
  (function(graph) {
    graph = {
      hash: {},
      index: {}
    };
    let {
      hash,
      index
    } = graph;
    hash = {
      "graph-data": [
        [{
          name: "country",
          dataset: []
        }],
        [{
          name: "occupation",
          dataset: []
        }],
        [{
          name: "age",
          dataset: []
        }]
      ]
    };
    return function(acc, item) {
      hash[item.country] && hash["graph-data"][0][0].dataset[index[item.country]].count++;
      if (!hash[item.country]) {
        hash[item.country] = true;
        hash["graph-data"][0][0].dataset.push({
          value: item.country,
          count: 1,
          color: "#878BB6"
        });
        index[item.country] = hash["graph-data"][0][0].dataset.length - 1;
      }
      hash[item.occupation] && hash["graph-data"][1][0].dataset[index[item.occupation]].count++;
      if (!hash[item.occupation]) {
        hash[item.occupation] = true;
        hash["graph-data"][1][0].dataset.push({
          value: item.occupation,
          count: 1,
          color: "#878BB6"
        });
        index[item.occupation] = hash["graph-data"][1][0].dataset.length - 1;
      }
      hash[item.age] && hash["graph-data"][2][0].dataset[index[item.age]].count++;
      if (!hash[item.age]) {
        hash[item.age] = true;
        hash["graph-data"][2][0].dataset.push({
          value: item.age,
          count: 1,
          color: "#878BB6"
        });
        index[item.age] = hash["graph-data"][2][0].dataset.length - 1;
      }
      acc = hash;
      return acc;
    };
  })(Object.create(null)), {}
);
console.log(...mapping["graph-data"]);
```

Comment: 1. Use a utility function like ramda's `groupBy` for the grouping transforms ([quick, incomplete example code](https://runkit.com/jonah/596ad5bb7f76150011faf2fd).  2. Don't couple your graph coloring logic to the grouping logic.  Do it in a separate pass.  You'll still have linear performance.

Comment: @Jonah thanks. I am not a fan of libraries. However, this code could definitely use some refactoring and optimize, I might change out the object for a Map or a Set, I am really not sure. This is where I am currently stuck right now  :( .  You are right, I should do the colors in a separate pass.

Comment: I'd _strongly_ advise you to reconsider that opinion.  You'll be using libraries whether you want to or not -- the only question is how good they'll be.  It's a great exercise to write things like this yourself, but it should be just that.  At some point, you should be re-using high-level functions to solve your problems.   You'll want a light, well-designed, well-tested library when you do.  And btw, `reduce`, `map`, `some`, etc are just library functions that have been standardized into the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use a splitted approach, one for collecting a group with a given key and another for mapping the results into an array in the wanted form.

Basically `groupBy(array, key, pattern)` uses a given array with the data, the key for the value for grouping and an optional pattern for the result set of the grouped and counted values.

Main part is a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for collecting counts of specified group with a key of the object.

In a loop all groups are either used or if not exist, created. After that, a simple increment takes place.

For the wanted result, the wanted keys for grouping are iterated and a new data structure for any key is created in the wanted style.

```js
function groupBy(array, key, pattern) {
    var map = new Map;

    array.forEach(function (o) {
        var group = map.get(o[key]) || Object.assign({ value: o[key], count: 0 }, pattern);
        if (!map.has(o[key])) {
            map.set(o[key], group);
        }
        group.count++;
    });
    return [...map.values()];
}

var object = { dataset: [{ name: "Sarah", age: "23", gender: "female", country: "australia", occupation: "student" }, { name: "Randy", age: "19", gender: "male", country: "america", occupation: "student" }, { name: "Roger", age: "32", gender: "male", country: "germany", occupation: "software professional" }, { name: "Maverick", age: "10", gender: "male", country: "america", occupation: "student" }, { name: "Riya", age: "25", gender: "female", country: "australia", occupation: "software professional" }, { name: "Glade", age: "30", gender: "female", country: "India", occupation: "teacher" }] },
    result = ['country', 'occupation', 'age'].map(key => ({
        name: key,
        dataset: groupBy(object.dataset, key, { color: '#878BB6' })
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I hate how simple, clean, and short this answer is. I hate it!!!  : )

Answer (score 3):

You need to abstract your code, which is not as difficult as it sounds. The idea is to first bucket your data based on a specified list of properties, then to flatten it into an appropriate form.

See the simple implementation below. For your data, the following will produce the desired output:

```
new DataPlucker(['age', 'country', 'occupation'], object.dataset).pluckAndFlatten()
```

Read the comments to better understand how it works.

```
class DataPlucker {
  // `properties` is a list of strings ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']
  // `data` is of the form [obj1, obj2, obj3], where objN is of the form
  // `{ prop1: val1, prop2: val2, ... }`
  constructor (properties, data) {
    this.properties = properties
    this.data = data

    // Given the above list, we want `this.bucket` to be an object of the form
    // { prop1: {}, prop2: {}, prop3: {} }, we do this by mapping each property
    // specified in the list to an object of the form { prop1: {} }, before
    // aggregating into a single object via `Object.assign`.
    this.bucket = Object.assign.apply(null, properties.map(prop => {
      return { [prop]: {} }
    }))
  }

  pluckAndFlatten () {
    // `pluck` the data first, so that `this.bucket` is of the correct form.
    this._pluck()

    // Recall, `this.bucket` is an object with keys equal to the entries of
    // `this.properties`, the value associated with each key is another object.
    //
    // For example, suppose `this.bucket` is of the form
    // {
    //   prop1: {
    //     val1: { value: val1, count: num1, /* ... */ },
    //     val2: { value: val2, count: num2, /* ... */ },
    //   },
    //   /* ... */
    // }
    // Our goal is to transform each propN in the above object into another
    // object of the form (*)
    // { name: prop1, dataset: [ prop1.val1, prop1.val2, /* etc */ ] }
    // and to then collect these transformed objects into an array.
    //
    // Hence, for each key in `this.bucket` (alternatively: each property in
    // `this.properties`), map each key to an object an the form (*):
    return Object.keys(this.bucket).map(key => {
      // `key` will be equal to `prop1`, `prop2`, and so on. All we need to do
      // is grab the values of `this.bucket[key]`:
      return { name: key, dataset: Object.values(this.bucket[key]) }      
    })
  }

  _pluck () {
    // For each element in the data set and for each property in the property
    // list, either update the count in `this.bucket` or create a new object.
    this.data.forEach(datum => {
      this.properties.forEach(property => {
        this._updateOrCreate(property, datum[property])
      })
    })
  }

  _updateOrCreate (key, val) {
    if (this.bucket[key][val]) {
      this.bucket[key][val].count += 1
    } else {
      this.bucket[key][val] = { value: val, count: 1 }
    }
  }
}
```